# Multiplicative order and primitive roots

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime and r an integer coprime to $p$. I am trying to show that if $r^{p-1}/q$ is not equal to $1$ for all primes $q$ dividing $p$, then $r$ is a primitive root modulo $p$. The hard part is that we only need consider the primes $q$ dividing $p$ for some reason. Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $r$ is **not** a primitive root, then $r$ has order $m$ where $m$ is a proper divisor of $p-1$. But then  $m$ divides $\frac{p-1}{q}$ for some prime divisor of $q-1$.

If this does not seem obvious, note that $\frac{p-1}{m}$ is divisible by *some* prime $q$. Thus $\frac{p-1}{m}=kq$ for some $k$. But then $km=\frac{p-1}{q}$, so $m$ divides $\frac{m-1}{q}$.

It follows that $r^{(p-1)/q}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. But the problem specified that 
$r^{(p-1)/q}\not \equiv 1\pmod{p}$.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I could always take q to be the smallest prime dividing p-1.

Comment: Not really. Want (the smallest) prime dividing $\frac{p-1}{m}$ where $m$ is the order of $r$.

Answer (score 2):

[Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29) tells us, that the smallest $k$ satisfying $r^k=1$ in $\mathbb Z_p^*$ divides $|\mathbb Z_p^*|=p-1$. So there is some $a$, such that $ka=p-1$ for this $k$.

Assume, $r$ is not primitive, then $a>1$, so you can write $a=qb$, where $q$ is a prime. Now $kqb=p-1$. Then $r^k=1$ implies $r^{kb}=1$ and
$$1=r^{kb}=r^{\frac{p-1}{q}}$$
is a contradiciton to your precondition.